# search in document by Regex

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

Can anyone help me write a correct Regular Expression for finding the following string.

```
Know_str1 Unknown_str Known_str2
```

And replace it with

```
/*Know_str1*/ Unknown_str Known_str2
```

Without any change on `Unknown_str`  and `Known_str2`

Comment: Know_str1 is repeated many times . i just search for Know_str1 that is founded with Know_str2 in the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some assumptions about what the unknown string is but try:

```
Find:{Know_str1} {:i} {Known_str2}
Replace with:/*\1*/ \2 \3
```

If you care about whitespace around the unknown string:

```
Find:{Know_str1}{{:Wh}+{:i}{:Wh}+{Known_str2}}
Replace with:/*\1*/\2
```

Comment: thanks sir Blt , your Regex is very powerful and . that is what i search about .

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you want...

```
var s = "Know_str1 Unknown_str Known_str2";
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(Know_str1)(.*Known_str2)");
var m = regex.Replace(s, "/* $1 */ $2");
```